# Comparison of $(\log^* n)!$ and $(n\log n)^b$

Tags: asymptotics

How can I compare $(\log^*n)!$ with $(n\log n)^b$?
I know that $n^b<n!$.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with algorithms per se.

Answer (score 2):

For sufficiently large values of $n$, and $b>0$:

$$
( \log^*n )! < ( \log \log n )! < (\log \log n)^{\log \log n} = 2^{(\log\log n) \log \log \log n} \in o(2^{b \log n}) \subset o( (n \log n)^b ).
$$